# How do you remove the standard Start Button from the Win 11 Taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I have just upgraded a Win 10 machine to Win 11. I succesfully installed Open Shell and moved the taskbar icons to the left. Unfortunately, unlike in Win 10 where the Open Shell button replaced the Windows Start one, it sat strangely above it. I have tried quite hard to remove the Win Start button from the taskbar but to no avail. I moved the icons back to the centre which solved the weird superimposition but I still can't remove the totally superflous (to me) Win button (The Open Shell icon remains bottom left). I want to control my taskbar and I want rid of the Windows button. Is this possible and, if so, how.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, no.  Third party start replacements, yes.

Be aware that Feature updates may change the game as well.

Also, the shell replacements hide Start with their own product.  You cannot actually delete the Start button.

There are 3 alternatives in the early part of this [article](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/windows-11-replace-start-menu).

> Fortunately, with a third-party app and possibly a registry tweak, you
> can get a different style of Start menu that's closer to the look and
> feel of Windows 7 than Windows 10 and gives you lots of options. There
> are a few different utilities out there but I tested with the three
> most popular: Open-Shell (formerly Classic Shell), a free open-source
> app, StartAllBack and Start11, which cost $4.99 each and have a lot
> more functionality.
>
> Start11 has a "Windows 10 style" option that looks the most like
> Windows 10's Start Menu, including its tiles area. It also gives you
> more design options such as the ability to set a texture behind the
> taskbar. And it lets you move the taskbar to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native windows support to hide the windows icon on the start bar.

### third party

The link in Jahn's answer is broken.
here's the correct link https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/windows-11-replace-start-menu

It talks about changing the start bar in windows 11 to the classic windows 10 startbar. it does not discuss how to hide the icon.

Since these solutions are aimed at customising your task bar, i would not recommend paying for them in the hope that they can hide the icon instead.

As of now, there seems to be no way to do what you want.

##### free solution

- Open-Shell, which doesn't support hiding the start icon. see this forum [post](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=627)

##### payed solutions:

- StartAllBack
- Start11